# Vim changes files after using make

Tags: vim

I bind F5 to make:

```
map <F5> :make clean && make <cr>
```

After I do make, it always replaces the current file by another file in the folder which I opened before. For example, I am editing `part1.c` and did make, and then it replaces the current file by `part2.c` after returning from make. Have no clue why this is happening.

Comment: Is it appropriate to edit the title of the page in order to make this easier to find in searches?  Something like "Vim changes files after using make" seems more descriptive.

Comment: @benjifisher Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to use vim's `:make` command, which is basically a wrapper for the external `make` program?  If you want to use the external `make` directly, then use `!make clean && make`.

Under `:help make`, it says

```
...
7. If [!] is not given the first error is jumped to.
```

So my guess is that you have an error in `part2.c`.

If you have accidentally discovered vim's built-in `:make` command, then you should consider learning about it.

```
:help :make
:help quickfix
```

Comment: That solves the issue... Surprised that vim has a built-in make command!

Comment: Vim calls itself "the programmer's test editor."  A lot of behavior, like default matching with `%` and indenting, has defaults tailored to C code.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in `:make` command executes the configured `'makeprg'` (default is `make`, the external program), **and jumps to the first error**. To avoid the latter, add a `!` to the command: `:make!`.